# How to use two objects from a pooled list in one script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pooling

I am trying to understand object pooling.  I am able to get the script to pull one object at a time, but I need to be able to pull three or more from the list at the same time.

My object pooling script is big, so I don't really want to share the whole thing unless it is necessary.

I need to be able to change the location of the spawn of a flame, so I created a script to do that:

```
 private void CreateWavesForFlames(GameObject flame, float xBase, float xDisplacement, float dropHeight)
 {
    flame.transform.position = new Vector3(xBase + xDisplacement, dropHeight, 0);
    flame.SetActive(true); //this turn the pooled object on
}
```

So I need to spawn three flames at the same time and change their spawn locations

The wave call would look something like this:

```
void Wave1() {
    Debug.Log("Wave1");
    tempGOHolder = gm.GetLargeFire();


    CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder, 0, 0, 12);
    CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder, 10, 0, 12);
    CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder, 15, 0, 12);

}
```

What happens is only one fire flame is created and it uses the last CreatWavesForFlames.  I need the three to be different.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. that is what is expected from your code.  if you want 3 different flame objects, Then you are going to have to do this(assuming "gm" is your pool manager object):

```
tempGOHolder = gm.GetLargeFire();
CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder, 0, 0, 12);

tempGOHolder = gm.GetLargeFire();
CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder, 10, 0, 12);

tempGOHolder = gm.GetLargeFire();
CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder, 15, 0, 12);
```

Comment: Awesome.  Such a simple solution.  I didn't think I could repeat, but apparently I can!  Thank you.

Comment: You could also extend your `GetLargeFire()` to return an Array of GameObjects and loop over the Array instead of repeating these lines n times

Comment: I will have to figure that out.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered but I think there is a better solution. The answer above is great. Assuming you want to make your code shorter by not repeatedly calling the `GetLargeFire()` function, you can use the method below.

Lets say that your `GetLargeFire()` function in your pool script looks like this:

```
GameObject GetLargeFire()
{
    return availableGameObject;
}
```

You can create an overload of the `GetLargeFire()` function that fills up an array that is passed to it. I wouldn't recommend returning array because that allocates memory, therefore making your pooling script useless. Filling up array that is passed in is better.

```
public void GetLargeFire(GameObject[] gOBJ, int amountToReturn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gOBJ.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < amountToReturn)
        {
            gOBJ[i] = GetLargeFire();
        }
        else
        {
            //Fill the rest with null to override what was inside of it previously
            gOBJ[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to use it like the example you have in your question, you should declare `tempGOHolder` as an array and choose a number you you think is enough for it. We will use **3** for this example.

```
GameObject[] tempGOHolder;

void Start()
{
    tempGOHolder = new GameObject[3];
}

void Wave1() {
    Debug.Log("Wave1");
    gm.GetLargeFire(tempGOHolder, 3);
    CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder[0], 0, 0, 12);
    CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder[1], 10, 0, 12);
    CreateWavesForFlames(tempGOHolder[2], 15, 0, 12);
}
```

You can even use loop to create Waves with `CreateWavesForFlames` with less code.